# How to print only first occurrence of python warning?

Tags: python, warnings

I have a function which is called at many different times. The function must print a warning, but only the first time. The warning should not be printed every time the function is called.

```
def func():
    if(condition):
        warnings.warn('warn message',RuntimeWarning)
```

How do I ensure that this warning is only printed the first time `condition` is true and not every subsequent time.

None of the other answers helped me. I came across `warning filters`, but I don't understand how to use that here.

Comment: A better idea would be to *heed* the warning and adjust the call to avoid `condition` being true.

Comment: You can use a decorator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48524984/how-to-print-only-first-occurrence-of-python-warning/48525340#48525340

Answer (score 4):

Solution could probably be found around there: https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warning-filter

```
warnings.simplefilter('once', RuntimeWarning)
```

Here custom solutions using decorators: you don't have to change your function implementation to a class, you keep the logic to catch the first warning separated from the rest of your code.

For warn:

```
def warn_only_once(function):
    function.already_warned = False
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with warnings.catch_warnings(record=function.already_warned):
            function.already_warned = not function.already_warned
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@warn_only_once
def test():
     warning.warn('hello', RuntimeWarning)
```

For raise:

```
def warn_only_once(function):
    function.already_warned = False
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        except RuntimeWarning as warning:
            if not function.already_warned:
               function.already_warned = True
               raise warning
    return wrapper

@warn_only_once
def test():
     raise RuntimeWarning('hello')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an auxiliary variable that starts being `false` and turns to `true` on the first warning.
If you must execute the function multiple times, an easy solution would be to wrap it inside a class, and store the variable in the instance of the class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_warning = False
    def func(self):
        if(condition) and not self.first_warning:
            warnings.warn('warn message',RuntimeWarning)
            self.first_warning = True

m = MyClass()
m.func()  # only the first time the condition is met, the warning will occur
m.func()
m.func()
```

Comment: How does this solve anything?  `first_warning` does not persist outside of the function; it will be `False` again the next time the function is called.

Comment: Yes, I originally misunderstood the question. I fixed the answer so it makes sense.